# Memory error while using decision trees because input file is too long

Tags: python, memory, decision-tree

I am using the following input file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjKoSi4rmMYZVm31LZ2Li92HM9USlu6A/view?usp=sharing 
I am trying to predict the value of the first column (either T or N) based on the values of the remaining columns(0s and 1s). I am using decision trees to make my predictions.
I am getting a memory error because of the line  `df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=X)`  in the `selection` function. I only got this memory error when I made the input file longer and I didn't get this error when the input file was short. How can I fix this? Here is a screenshot of the error I am getting:

[image]

```
 # Run this program on your local python 
# interpreter, provided you have installed 
# the required libraries. 

# Importing the required packages 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score 
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn import tree
import collections

import pydotplus
# Function importing Dataset 
column_count =0 
def importdata(): 
    balance_data = pd.read_csv( 'data1extended.txt', sep= ',') 
    row_count, column_count = balance_data.shape

    # Printing the dataswet shape 
    print ("Dataset Length: ", len(balance_data)) 
    print ("Dataset Shape: ", balance_data.shape) 
    print("Number of columns ", column_count)

    # Printing the dataset obseravtions 
    print ("Dataset: ",balance_data.head()) 
    balance_data['gold'] = balance_data['gold'].astype('category').cat.codes

    return balance_data, column_count 
def columns(balance_data): 
    row_count, column_count = balance_data.shape
    return column_count
# Function to split the dataset 
def splitdataset(balance_data, column_count): 

    # Separating the target variable 
    X = balance_data.values[:, 1:column_count] 
    Y = balance_data.values[:, 0] 

    # Splitting the dataset into train and test 
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( 
    X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100) 

    return X, Y, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test 

# Function to perform training with giniIndex. 
def train_using_gini(X_train, X_test, y_train): 

    # Creating the classifier object 
    clf_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini", 
            random_state = 100,max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=5) 

    # Performing training 
    clf_gini.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    return clf_gini 


# Function to make predictions 
def prediction(X_test, clf_object): 

    # Predicton on test with giniIndex 
    y_pred = clf_object.predict(X_test) 



    print("Predicted values:") 
    print(y_pred) 
    return y_pred 
  #Univariate selection 
def selection(column_count, data): 
  #  data = pd.read_csv("data1extended.txt")
    X = data.iloc[:,1:column_count]  #independent columns
    y = data.iloc[:,0]    #target column i.e price range
    #apply SelectKBest class to extract top 10 best features
    bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=5)
    fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
    dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
    print('heeey',dfscores)
    dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
    df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=X)
    #concat two dataframes for better visualization 
    featureScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)
    featureScores.columns = ['Specs','Score']  #naming the dataframe columns
    print(featureScores.nlargest(5,'Score'))  #print 10 best features
    return X,y,data,df
#Feature importance
def feature(X,y):    
    model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
    model.fit(X,y)
    print(model.feature_importances_) #use inbuilt class feature_importances of tree based classifiers
    #plot graph of feature importances for better visualization
    feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
    feat_importances.nlargest(5).plot(kind='barh')
    plt.show()
#Correlation Matrix 
def correlation(data, column_count):

    corrmat = data.corr()
    top_corr_features = corrmat.index
    plt.figure(figsize=(column_count,column_count))
    #plot heat map
    g=sns.heatmap(data[top_corr_features].corr(),annot=True,cmap="RdYlGn")
def generate_decision_tree(X,y):
     clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
     data_feature_names = ['callersAtLeast1T','CalleesAtLeast1T','callersAllT','calleesAllT','CallersAtLeast1N','CalleesAtLeast1N','CallersAllN','CalleesAllN','childrenAtLeast1T','parentsAtLeast1T','childrenAtLeast1N','parentsAtLeast1N','childrenAllT','parentsAllT','childrenAllN','ParentsAllN','ParametersatLeast1T','FieldMethodsAtLeast1T','ReturnTypeAtLeast1T','ParametersAtLeast1N','FieldMethodsAtLeast1N','ReturnTypeN','ParametersAllT','FieldMethodsAllT','ParametersAllN','FieldMethodsAllN']
     #generate model 
     model = clf.fit(X, y)
    # Create DOT data
     dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, feature_names=data_feature_names,class_names=y)

    # Draw graph
     graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  

    # Show graph
     Image(graph.create_png())
    # Create PDF
     graph.write_pdf("tree.pdf")

    # Create PNG
     graph.write_png("tree.png")
# Driver code  

def main(): 

    # Building Phase 
    data,column_count = importdata() 
    X, Y, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = splitdataset(data, column_count) 
    clf_gini = train_using_gini(X_train, X_test, y_train) 


    #tried to generate the fit value here and failed 
    X,y,dataheaders,df=selection(column_count,data)
    generate_decision_tree(X,y)

    feature(X,y)
    correlation(dataheaders,column_count)





if __name__=="__main__": 
    main()
```

Comment: have you ever considered getting more memory?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Python doesn’t limit memory usage on your program. It will allocate as much memory as your program needs until your computer is out of memory. The most you can do is reduce the limit to a fixed upper cap. That can be done with the resource module, but it isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: you can do that by getting more DIMM (or whatever is used in your PC) modules and install them into the motherboard.